# Vuex - Passing a state's object into another state's object

Tags: vue.js, state, store, vuex

In Vuex I'm trying to pass a state's object (a string in this case), into another state's object, but it is returning undefined.

```
state: {
   notifications: [
      { key: "success",
        notification: "Awesome " + this.theName + "! Success.", 
        redirectPath: "/home"
      },
      { key: "error",
        notification: "Oh no " + this.theName + "... Error.", 
        redirectPath: "/error"
      }
   ],
   theName: 'Ricky Bobby' // this would normally come from a mutation method - see below
}
```

The example above the `theName` is hard-coded just for testing but its value is coming from a mutation method. I know it is coming in into the store's state, because I am able to console log it. But the string interpolation inside the `notifications` object is not working. How can I pass that incoming value into the `notifications.notification` value?

I don't know if this helps, but here is the mutation example:

```
mutations: {
   loginSuccess(state, payload){
      state.theName = payload.uName;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There're two issues with your code. Firstly, `this` doesn't work the way you're trying to make it to do. In your question `this` inside each notification doesn't refer to the `state` or any other part of your code. Its value is the global window object or `undefined`, depends on whether you are in strict mode:

```js
const object = {
   propName: this,
};

console.log(object.propName);
```

Secondly, you code is asynchronous, so `theName` would change from time to time, but you never actually redefine message strings in your notifications. And they won't be 'recalculated' by itself:

```js
let surname = 'Whyte';

const object = {
  fullName: 'Pepe ' + surname,
};

console.log(object.fullName);

setTimeout(() => {
  surname = 'White';
  console.log(object.fullName);
  console.log('the value of \'surname\' variable is ' + surname + ' though.');
}, 2000);
```

What you can do in your case is to define notification as a function:

```
notification(name) { return "Awesome " + name + "! Success."}
```

Then write a getter for notifications and pass a name to the function.

Or as an alternative you can refer to the object itself inside the function. Like this:

```js
let surname = 'Whyte';

const object = {
  person: {
    firstName: 'Pepe ',
    fullName: () => {
      return object.person.firstName + ' ' + surname;
    },
  }
};

console.log(object.person.fullName());
setTimeout(() => {
  object.person.firstName = 'Keke';
  console.log(object.person.fullName());
}, 1000);
```

UPD: I've made another example for you. It's hard to tell how exactly you are going to call this notifications, but here are two options you can access them the way you want ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oniondomes/xrxtygnL/)):

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    theName: 'Ricky Bobby',
    // accessing `theName` prop inside state (probably won't be possible in the real project or very inconvinient due to modularity)
    successNotificationInState: () => `Awesome ${store.state.theName}! Success.`,
  },
  // accessing the same prop with getter
  getters: {
    successNotification: (state) => `Awesome ${state.theName}! Success.`,
  },
  mutations: {
    loginSuccess(state, payload) {
      state.theName = payload.uName;
    },
  },
  actions: { // let's emulate a login
    login({
      commit
    }) {
      return new Promise(fullfil => {
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('logging in')
          const response = {
            uName: 'Keke',
            email: 'keke@gmail.com',
          }
          fullfil(response);
          commit('loginSuccess', response);
        }, 2000);
      });
    },
  },
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  data: {
    msgGetter: '',
    msgState: '',
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    login() {
      this.$store.dispatch('login').then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(this.$store);
        this.msgGetter = this.$store.getters.successNotification;
        this.msgState = this.$store.state.successNotificationInState();
      });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.login();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Message from state: {{msgState}}</p>
  <p>Message from getter: {{msgGetter}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would notification function work inside the object? Here is a more in-depth example of my actual code - https://codesandbox.io/s/jz85x88559

Comment: If you mean something like this: `notification() { return "Awesome " + this.theName + "! Success."}` It won't.

Comment: In such case `this` would refer to the closest block scope and it would be `notification`, not the state.

Comment: Yeah something like - { key: "success", notification(){ "Awesome " + this.theName + "! Success."}, redirectPath: "/home"}

Comment: aahh. I also tried as `state. theName` and that won't work, cause I'm already inside the state.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your example. I get the whole sync vs async issue, but beyond that I'm not following your train of thought.

Comment: Oh I see why you are confused, let me recall what my idea was when I was writing it. I'll come back with updated answer in case of success.

Comment: @sergio another example for you. Hope this time it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. I will check out your new example. Also for a more "real" example please check this link - https://codesandbox.io/s/jz85x88559 it may help illustrate my issue more clearly.